Why does beisbol need el?
I wrote a sentence:
Béisbol es muy divertido.

As a translation of 'Baseball is really fun.' And it was wrong.
The correct answer was:
El béisbol es muy divertido.

I wonder why my answer is wrong. This sentence does not refer to any specific baseball game or competition. It is just baseball itself.

Basically, in Spanish, you always need a determiner. It can be a definite article sure, as the answers below say, but it can also be adjectives like algun or ningun.

The definite article is used with abstract nouns.  Examples: el amor, la justicia.
In this context, beisbol is an abstract noun.  There is no physical object referred to, although many physical objects are used to play baseball.
Hence, the article:  el beisbol.

Any noun used in a generic way, be it concrete or abstract, will take the definite article in Spanish. In English, abstract nouns used generically take the zero article.

El béisbol es mi deporte favorito.
Baseball is my favorite sport.

In the case of concrete nouns, in English we tend to use the plural with the zero article. In Spanish, the definite article will be required once again.

Los jugadores de béisbol son muy rápidos.
Baseball players are very fast.

